Regulate voltage from 24V to 5V for radio receiver module
I'm going to make my own quadcopter. I plan to use 6s Lipo battery (24V). Radio receiver module accepts 5V input power source. Seems like voltage regulator will be overheated cause of big voltage difference. At the same time buck converter may produce noise that will interfere with the radio receiver

Your title says you want 3 V output but your text says 5 V. Could you edit to clarify? (In the meantime I've answered assuming 5 V is the correct value)

You need to know the current that will be drawn by the 5 V device when operating normally.  The power dissipated in a linear regulator is the voltage across the regulator (19 V in your case) times the current through it.  Once you know this value, you can evaluate different approaches.


Seems like voltage regulator will be overheated cause of big voltage difference.

As another answer said, this all depends on the current drawn by the load. If it's only a milliamp or two, a linear regulator could still be a viable option.

At the same time buck converter may produce noise that will interfere with the radio receiver

There is a bit of art to designing and laying out switching converters to minimize noise, but it can be done.
Another option might be to use a buck converter to reduce the voltage to something not too high above your load voltage like 6 or 7 V (for a 5 V load), and then use an LDO to drop the remaining voltage. This can give you pretty good efficiency (but not as good as just using a buck converter alone) with very low ripple in the supply to the load (but do design the circuit carefully as the ripple rejection of LDO's is often not so great at higher frequencies).
